# How to get SPUser object from SocialProfile in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, user-profile, object-model, spuser

How can I get the [SPUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.aspx) object associated to the profile from the [SocialProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofile.aspx) in Sharepoint 2010?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the login name of the user as specified in the msdn article you linked.
Then get the user for the given SPSite, since SharePoint users (and groups) are per site-collection:

```
SPWeb web = ...;
web.AllUsers["<loginName>"];
```

or if you want to create the user if it not already exits:

```
web.EnsureUser("<loginName>");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get the ID of the required user

```
UserProfile profile = GetProfile();
string userId = profile .MultiloginAccounts[0];
```

Second, get user from one of the following collections

```
web.AllUsers, web.Users or web.SiteUser
```

This article is about the differences http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/71d1c8e3-de32-4e3d-9f8c-7a9be13197f6/